# PHP MySql, Usar el resultado de un desplegable para otro desplegable

Tags: php, mysql, array

Aquí un novato en apuros, autodidacta y algo cabezota xD
Os cuento, tengo un desplegable, que toma sus valores de una tabla.

```
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label>Tema</label>
        <select name="busqueda1" class="form-control" id="busqueda1" placeholder="Tema">
        <option value=""></option>
                <?php
                $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM knd_tema order by tem_id");
                while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$valores['tem_id'].'">'.$valores['tem_descripcion'].' - '.$valores['tem_descripcion'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
        </select>           
    </div>
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, me muestra los resultados bien. Ahora quiero utilizar ese resultado para otro desplegable, que a su vez tambien saca los datos de otra tabla.

Y es donde ya me pierdo, no soy capaz de recuperar el valor anterior.

> 

```
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <label>Categoria</label>
        <select name="busqueda2" class="form-control" id="busqueda2" placeholder="Categoria">
        <option value=$_GET['busqueda1']>kk</option>
                <?php
                $query2 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM knd_categoria where cat_tema=".$_GET["busqueda1"]." order by cat_id");  
                while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$valores2['cat_id'].'">'.$valores2['cat_descripcion'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
        </select>           
    </div>
```

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano.

Gracias de antemano a tod@s.

Comment: Si los dos <select> se encuentran en la misma página y el segundo debe mostrar valores de acuerdo a lo que acabas de seleccionar en el primero, lo que quieres lograr se hace utilizando JQuery/AJAX. Hay muchos ejemplos en la web. Aqui te dejo uno: https://programacion.net/articulo/selects_dependientes_utilizando_jquery-_ajax_y_php_1740

Comment: Me encontré con ese problema y no sabia de la solución que comentas, lo que hice fue ponerlo en dos paginas, primero un desplegable, un "intro" y enlaza con otra pagina de la que recupero el valor y lo aplico. Pero voy a mirar lo que mandas, ya que todo lo que sea aprender algo nuevo me encanta. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, básicamente es lo que hacías, pero asignando el resultado de tu primer select, a una variable de PHP, y con esa realizar la nueva consulta.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label>Categoria</label>
    <select name="busqueda2" class="form-control" id="busqueda2" placeholder="Categoria">
        <?php
        // Obtener el valor seleccionado en el primer desplegable
        $busqueda1_value = $_GET['busqueda1'];

        // Realizar la consulta para el segundo desplegable
        $query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM knd_categoria WHERE cat_tema = $busqueda1_value ORDER BY cat_id");

        // Iterar sobre los resultados y mostrarlos en el desplegable
        while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $valores2['cat_id'] . '">' . $valores2['cat_descripcion'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>           
</div>
```

Comment: He probado lo que me comentas, mil gracias por la rapidez, y me encuentro con que el segundo desplegable no recibe el resultado del primero, o bien yo no se como comprobarlo. Hay alguna forma de poder mostar el valor de la variable, he probado con un echo pero no me muestra nada.

Comment: simplemente he puesto un  <?php echo "resultado" .$busqueda1_value;?> y no muestra nada en pantalla.

Comment: para saber el contenido de una variable "echo var_dump($nombre de tu variable)", te mostrara el contenido y tipo de la misma, puedes probar con eso.

Comment: Genial !!!! ya se como saber si la variable tiene o no los datos, voy a realizar pruebas con lo que me has comentado y te cuento despues.